# AES decryption with wrong key. how to hide the fact the key was wrong?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm using [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js). when i use AES.decrypt with the wrong key, i noticed it usually has a negative "sigBytes", which tells me i used the wrong key. why is this possible? does it have something to do with invalid padding? I've tried different modes of AES, same issue. is it even possible for AES to not acknowledge failure?

is there a standard encryption algo that will decrypt to random bytes with no indication of success or failure?

Comment: Which mode of operation are you using? MCVE?

Comment: CBC. tried these available options with same issue: CFB, CTR, OFB, ECB

Comment: Probably padding, yeah, although CFB, CTR, and OFB shouldn’t have it. Maybe CryptoJS just pads in those modes anyway. Looking for an option, but can I ask why you want this?

Comment: i want to make it extra hard to crack, even if they have my password in their dictionary, and decrypt using the right key, they might not even realize it.

Comment: That doesn’t really make it harder to crack unless what you’re encrypting looks completely random as well. (After all, if you’re trying to crack something, it’s fastest just to try decrypting one block.) Better to make getting the AES key from the password slow using a password-based KDF (like bcrypt, scrypt, Argon, PBKDF2) to slow down attacks and use a strong password.

Comment: agreed. encrypting bitcoin private keys / seeds is one use case, which does look completely random. (i'm also using bcrypt, scrypt, and pbkdf2)

Comment: Okay, looks like the option is `padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding`. (You’re using… all three of those?)

Comment: How would you know if the password is correct when you decrypt? That's how the attacker will know.

Comment: i tried NoPadding option but cannot get AES to work at all with it (even when using correct keys)... yes i'm using all 3, lol, no reason not to

Comment: AES doesn't work without padding, right? maybe NoPadding option is there just so you can provide your own? that doesn't help me

Comment: AES in CFB, CTR, and OFB modes should work fine without padding. Can you show the relevant encryption/decryption code?

Comment: ...wow i'm dumb. didn't realize padding was actually the issue, and so i never tried those combos. looks like it's working and doesn't acknowledge failures! post as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  stream based ciphers do generally never report failure. Basically, if you know that the ciphertext size is the same as the plaintext size then failure cannot be reported. This is because general purpose ciphers generally accept *any* message, meaning that there is exactly one ciphertext for each plaintext for a certain bit length and vice versa, independent on what key is used. Such a 1:1 mapping is called a *pseudo random permutation* or PRP. As each ciphertext leads back to a valid plaintext message, there is no error to return.

All stream ciphers (such as ChaCha) and block cipher streaming modes will therefore have this property. Streaming modes are modes that do not require padding and should therefore not expand the ciphertext size compared with the plaintext size. Of course, if you *actively* indicate that padding is required you may destroy this particular property. Currently the most common counter mode is probably CTR mode, also because it is used for almost all *authenticated* modes. CFB/OFB are generally considered for legacy purposes only.

Beware that an adversary may still get information depending on the information in the plaintext. Generally a key can be found even if very little plaintext is known (a JPEG header would for instance easily be sufficient knowledge). Other operations on wrong plaintext may also easily indicate failure (turning the receiving side into a so called *plaintext oracle*).